# How to construct multiple AND logic in match stage of MongoDB aggregation Java query?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

I'm new to Mongodb in Java and I'm running some aggregation and got stuck with this.

I'm trying to filter as the following

```
{
    "$and": [
        {"_id.day": {"$gte": 25}},
        {"_id.month": {"$gte": 2}},
        {"_id.year": {"$gte": 2020}},
    ],
    "$and": [
        {"_id.day": {"$lt": 26}},
        {"_id.month": {"$lte": 3}},
        {"_id.year": {"$lte": 2020}},
    ]
}
```

Here is what I'm trying so far but it's not working as I expected

```
Aggregates.match(
   Filters.and(
        Filters.gte("_id.day", startOfRange.getDayOfMonth()),
        Filters.gte("_id.month", startOfRange.getMonthOfYear()),
        Filters.gte("_id.year", startOfRange.getYear()))
    Filters.and(
        Filters.lt("_id.day", endOfRange.getDayOfMonth()),
        Filters.lte("_id.month", endOfRange.getMonthOfYear()),
        Filters.lte("_id.year", endOfRange.getYear()))
)
```

I follow this tutorial: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/builders/filters/#examples-1

I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to query and get correct results from the `mongo` shell?

Comment: Can you provide your data model? It looks like your _id field is also a document from your query which is not default case.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, I can get the result from mongo shell

Comment: Can you tell what is the difference in the results you are seeing?

Comment: With the following 4 documents your first query doesn't work correctly: `{ "_id" : { "day" : 25, "month" : 2, "year" : 2020 } }, { "_id" : { "day" : 25, "month" : 4, "year" : 2020 } }, { "_id" : { "day" : 3, "month" : 5, "year" : 2020 } }, { "_id" : { "day" : 10, "month" : 5, "year" : 2020 } }`.

Comment: Note that you cannot compare dates correctly the way you have constructed the query.

Comment: Thanks for your time @prasad_. But I've convinced my boss to use Date object instead of keeping day, month, year values separated. Now it's much more easier. One again, thank you.